# Parse Kafka message to create XML file

Tags: java, xml, apache-kafka

I am fairly new to Apache Kafka and am looking to create a small microservice/program (probably in Java) to consume messages from Kafka and parse them to build an XML file. I already have messages appearing in my single Kafka Topic (the Publisher is a third-party application) but I then need to parse them in real-time (so I believe some sort of bash script may be out of the question).

I also have very little Java knowledge but am currently trying to learn the basics. Ultimately we would build the XML file and then make a POST request using curl to send the file to an HTTPS gateway.

My work and existing knowledge is solely around the application that is sending the messages into Kafka - a marketing automation solution - so I am unfamiliar with how to process Kafka messages afterwards.

If there are any alternative light-weight solutions that already exist that I should be looking at then please let me know. If anyone is able to shed some light on how I might begin to approach making a Java application, that would be hugely appreciated.

Also, if more information is required (e.g. around the structure of the Kafka messages and/or XML file) then I am happy to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this series - https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

> I am unfamiliar with how to process Kafka messages afterwards.

You can setup `value.deserializer=StringDeserializer` in your consumer config, similar to how you might have something similar in the producer.

From there, you consume the messages in a polling loop (examples of this and how to build a Java application are available elsewhere); I would recommend using a higher-level library like Spring-Kafka or Vert.x or Apache Camel for this, rather than direct Kafka client, however.

From there, you can use [Jackson-XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) for example to parse an XML string into a Java POJO and operate on that